# Advanced Remove Array Duplicated

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

I have 3 arrays.

```
Array 1 = {1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3}
Array 2 = {a,a,a,a,e,e,b,b}
Array 3 = {z,z,z,z,z,z,z,z}
```

I would like to remove all duplicates from array 1 and also remove the same element at said duplicate in the other arrays to keep them all properly linked.

I know you can use .Distinct().ToArray() to do this for one array, but then the other arrays would not have the elements removed as well.

The result would look like this.

```
Array 1 = {1,2,3}
Array 2 = {a,e,b}
Array 3 = {z,z,z}
```

I'm guessing the only way to solve this would be the following.

```
For(int a = 0; a < Array1.count; a++) {
    For(int b = a + 1; b < Array1.count; b++) {
      if(Array1[a]==Array1[b]) {
        Array1.RemoveAt(b);
        Array2.RemoveAt(b);
        Array3.RemoveAt(b);
      }
    }
}
```

Would be nice to find a simple predefined function however!

Comment: Are you sure you should *really* have three arrays, rather than a single array where each element is composed of the three different values? I always get nervous when you've got multiple collections which need to be kept in lock-step...

Comment: What can't you do `.Distinct().ToArray()` for the other two arrays as well?

Comment: How about posting some actual code, your problem is elsewhere, Distinct() should work

Comment: Your sample data shows that the other two arrays have the same repeating elements as the first. Is this always the case, or can they have unrelated values? Also, could the values be repeated later in the sequence, for example 1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,1

Comment: Array 1 and 2 will always have data that matches. Array 3 could be same across all entries. I can't use distinct on all arrays because then array 3 would only have 1 element and would ruin all associated array values, especially if these arrays have 100s of entries which they usually do.

Comment: This seems highly prone to error. Can Array 3 be {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}?  If so, then which element is the right one to keep and which dupes in Array 1 should be deleted?

Comment: Array 3 will always have the same entry if the element in Array 1 is equal. This data set is highly unique and this is the only way to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var distinctIndexes = array1
    .Select((item, idx) => new { Item = item, Index = idx })
    .GroupBy(p => p.Item)
    .Select(grp => grp.First().Index);

var result1 = distinctIndexes.Select(i => array1[i]).ToArray();
var result2 = distinctIndexes.Select(i => array2[i]).ToArray();
var result3 = distinctIndexes.Select(i => array3[i]).ToArray();
```

Note this won't necessarily use the first unique element from the first array. If you need to do that you can calculate the indexes as

```
var distinctIndexes = array1
    .Select((item, idx) => new { Item = item, Index = idx })
    .Aggregate(new Dictionary<int, int>(), (dict, i) =>
    {
        if (! dict.ContainsKey(i.Item))
        {
            dict[i.Item] = i.Index;
        }
        return dict;
    })
    .Values;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider what data structure you're using carefully. Is this "remove" operation likely to happen all at once? How often? (I'm not challenging your use of Array necessarily, just a general tip, but your scenario seems weird). Also, you did not explain if this is an index-based removal or an element based removal. If I was implementing this, I would be tempted to create a new Array and add all remaining elements to the new Array in a loop, ignoring the elements you want to remove. Then simply reassign the reference with '='. Of course, that depends on the maximum expected size of the Array, since a copy like I suggested would take up more memory (usually wouldn't be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of a clean way to do what you're asking, but this is a generic example of doing what you asked?

```
static void RemoveDupes(ref Array a1, ref Array a2, ref Array a3)
{
    Type a1t, a2t, a3t;
    int newLength, ni, oi;
    int[] indices;

    a1t = a1.GetType().GetElementType();
    a2t = a1.GetType().GetElementType();
    a3t = a1.GetType().GetElementType();


    Dictionary<object, List<int>> buckets = new Dictionary<object, List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        object val = a1.GetValue(i);
        if (buckets.ContainsKey(val))
            buckets[val].Add(i);
        else
            buckets.Add(val, new List<int> { i });
    }

    indices = buckets.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Count > 1).SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Skip(1)).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
    newLength = a1.Length - indices.Length;

    Array na1 = Array.CreateInstance(a1t, newLength);
    Array na2 = Array.CreateInstance(a2t, newLength);
    Array na3 = Array.CreateInstance(a3t, newLength);

    oi = 0;
    ni = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
    {
        while (oi < indices[i])
        {
            na1.SetValue(a1.GetValue(oi), ni);
            na2.SetValue(a2.GetValue(oi), ni);
            na3.SetValue(a3.GetValue(oi), ni);
            oi++;
            ni++;
        }
        oi++;
    }
    while (ni < newLength)
    {
        na1.SetValue(a1.GetValue(oi), ni);
        na2.SetValue(a2.GetValue(oi), ni);
        na3.SetValue(a3.GetValue(oi), ni);
        oi++;
        ni++;
    }
    a1 = na1;
    a2 = na2;
    a3 = na3;
}
```